# Move form visual studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way i could move or center my VB.net form in Visual Studio 2010?

I'm asking because whenever my toolbox is open, it hides my form and it's getting annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the top of the toolbox is a button that looks like a pin which toggles auto-hide. Click it and everything will move over so you can see the form and toolbox at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

also, if you don't want the toolbox to auto hide, you can move it to the right side of the window, out of your way.